# Copy rows from a table into a near identical table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables 'exp_bookmarks' and 'exp_favorites' that basically contain the same information....

**exp_bookmarks** columns...

[image: exp_bookmarks columns]

**exp_favorites** columns...

[image: exp_favorites columns]

I basically want to copy all the data from exp_bookmarks into exp_favorites table.
The only problem would be that values in the bookmarks_id column might match with the values in the favorites_id and they would all need to be unique.

Not sure if this is an appropriate place to ask but can't think of anywhere else to try and get help, so any pointers would be appreciated! Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement to insert the results of a `SELECT` statement into the table. Just leave out the `bookmarks_id` and `favorites_id` columns, and it will assign new IDs (I'm assuming this is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column -- if it isn't, it probably should be).

```
INSERT INTO exp_favorites (type, author_id, entry_id, member_id, site_id, entry_date, notes, public)
SELECT type, author_id, entry_id, member_id, site_id, entry_date, notes, public
FROM exp_bookmarks
```

Comment: @Hogan, yes.  Why would you not?

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to confirm whether it's an AUTO_INCREMENT column or not? (I'm pretty sure it is.)

Comment: @Sev09 - Because I thought that was the point of the question.

Comment: use `SHOW CREATE TABLE exp_favorites` or `DESCRIBE exp_favorites`

Comment: Brill, yes it's auto_increment. Thank you again, very much appreciated!